# I have an Eclipse Problem, where I can't even write a Hello World

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse and JDK 12.0.2, jet I cannot even do a simple Hello World, Eclipse gives me an error in my System.out.prinln which says: "expected token @". I have it installed on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have no clue what to do.

-

-

Comment: Please post your code, seems you missed it out.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it is difficult to help you there, however the following code will work

```
public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");        
    }
}
```

The fact that you say Eclipse gives you an error saying expected token, it sounds as if you have the project set up correctly and it may just be a missing semicolon or closing parenthesis etc

Comment: thank you for your help, i was away from java for a couple of weeks and forgot some things